# codesign fail: User canceled the operation

Tags: ios, code-signing

Seemingly out of the blue, an application that was building okay started giving this message:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign (my-identity) --resource-rules=/(path)/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /(path)/MyApp.app.xcent /(path)/MyApp.app

/(path)/MyApp.app: User canceled the operation.
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

The `codesign` command looks correct (the example above omits the items in brackets); the SHA1 hash of the identity matches an identity printed by `security find-identity`, and the provisioning profile is present and is the correct one for the app I'm trying to sign.

I've only found a few mentions of this specific error, and I've tried the things suggested:

- Rebooting
- Locking and unlocking the keychain

Looking for suggestions as to what to try next.

Comment: Just to ensure everything is good, have you double checked that your developer certificate and your development provisioning profiles are still valid? I only mention this because you've already tried checking that your keychain is unlocked.  I would also try a fresh, clean project and see if the issue replicates with a fresh project so you know if it's a project, or system related issue.

Comment: I just create a new project, tried to build for iOS Device, and same issue. So it doesn't seem like it's the project.

Comment: Well that is a good thing, now you know it isn't something in your project that changed.  Try this before building ... Connect the device to your computer, start up Xcode, open the Organizer window, select the device in the left window pane, ensure that the device has a green light next to it in the left pane, and that the button 'use for development' does _not_ show up on the right window pane.  If that button does show up, click it to enable the device for development.

Comment: Use for development does not show up.  I'm not sure that would matter, when building for "iOS Device" (the device target you get when no device is plugged in).  Still unable to build.

Comment: If you don't plug your device into the machine when choosing iOS Device, it can't build the application to the 'iOS Device'.  The only time I choose iOS Device without connecting a device is when I am doing a production build of my application for publishing.  In that case you have to choose "Archive" from the Product menu.

Comment: You can choose "iOS Device" and do a standard build. I just tried it. But in my case, any build other than a simulator build (any build that needs to be signed) is failing.

Comment: How do you perform a "standard" build? The only build options available in Xcode, version 5.1.1, under the product menu are 1) run, 2) test, 3) profile, 4) analyze, and 5) archive.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 6, although I think the options are the same - look a bit farther down the menu and there's simply an option called "Build", Cmd-B.